# Expanding Date Command inside single quotes in linux

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, date

I am new to linux. I am wondering why date command is not expanding inside single quotes.

so if i give command like below

```
d=$(date +%m%d) 
echo 'A1D$d'
```

Output is `A1D$d`

But If i give without quotes its working...

```
d=$(date +%m%d) 
    echo A1D$d
```

Output is  `A1D0603`

Can anyone pls help me in this

I need **date command to expand in the single quote** becoz....in **aws api** commands i need to used **date command inside the single quotes** like below

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D$(date +%m%d)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE
```

Comment: What's wrong with the command at the end? It seems okay

Comment: Your command is ok. It expands as expected. Can provide details why you think its not working?

Comment: Single-quotes within double-quotes do NOT prevent expansion `echo "foo'$(date)'"`

Answer (score 1):

In bash, variable substitution `$d` and also command substitution `$(date +%m%d)` will both be performed inside outer double quotes, but not inside outer single quotes.

The example that you have:

```
"Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D$(date +%m%d)')]"
```

should already work, because the *outer* quotes are double quotes.  The inner quotes are not interpreted by the shell, but instead are treated literally as part of the string.  You can see that if you add an `echo` to the start of the command to see what is being produced.

If you need to use single quotes (for example, in order to protect some other variable from being substituted) and then want to allow a variable to be substituted, then you need to end the single quotes.  The quotes do not need to be around the whole string, just some group of characters within it that you want to protect.  For example:

```
d=hello
echo '$b'$d
echo $d'$c'
echo '$b'$d'$c'
```

gives:

```
$bhello
hello$c
$bhello$c
```

Separately though, there is some problem at the end of your command line:

```
>> "$FILESIZE
```

It is not clear what that is meant to say, because firstly the quotes here are unmatched, but secondly, following `>>` should be the name of the file to append redirected output to, and the variable name `FILESIZE` doesn't suggest that it will contain a filename.  You should check what you have here.

Answer (score 1):

In bash  when you use `'` it will not substitute variable , So you need to use `"`  to get the variable substitution done . But when a `'` comes inside a `"` the variable substitution will happen , So ideally the command line provided above should work without any issue .
eg:

```
s=test
$ echo $s
test
$ echo "$s"
test
$ echo '$s'
$s
$ echo "'$s'"
'test'
$ echo "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D$(date +%m%d)')]"
Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D0604')]
```

To identify how your variables getting substituted in bash , run bash in debug mode 
using `set -x` then run the command

```
$ set -x
~
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D$(date +%m%d)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}'
+ awk '{print $2, $4}'
++ date +%m%d
+ aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, '\''A1D0604'\'')]' --output text
~
~
```

So I believe our command line should work without any change . (To revert debug mode to normal `set +x`)